# React mapping or looping through two lists

Tags: reactjs

Good day!

I am relatively new to React and would like to know if there is a solution to my problem. I have two lists:

```
const countriesList = ["Germany", "Spain", "France"];
const seasonsList = ["Spring", "Summer", "Fall", "Winter"];
```

From these two lists, I create dropdowns where a user can select any combination of the two lists. for example: Germany and Fall, or France and Spring, etc.
Depending on the selection of the dropdowns, I return a value from a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{
  "grm_spring": "In Spring time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "grm_summer": "In Summer time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "grm_fall": "In Fall time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "grm_winter": "In Winter time in Germany, words words words ...",

  "spn_spring": "In Spring time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "spn_summer": "In Summer time in Germany, words words words ...",

etc...
}
```

So, for each combination, there is a value in the dictionary. For example, if Germany and Fall are selected, `grm_fall` will be used from the dictionary.

At this point, I go through each possible combination using a switch like this:

```
export default function ReturnComboHeading(props) {
  const { country, season } = props;
  const dict_main = require("./dict_main.json");

  var selectGRMCard1;
  var selectSPNCard1;
  var selectFRNCard1;

  switch ([country, season].join(",")) {
    case "Germany,Spring":
      selectGRMCard1 = dict_main.grm_spring;
      break;
    case "Germany,Summer":
      selectGRMCard1 = dict_main.grm_summer;
      break;
    case "Germany,Fall":
      selectGRMCard1 = dict_main.grm_fall;
      break;
    case "Germany,Winter":
      selectGRMCard1 = dict_main.grm_winter;
      break;

    case "Spain,Spring":
      selectSPNCard1 = dict_main.spn_spring;
      break;
    case "Spain,Summer":
      selectSPNCard1 = dict_main.spn_summer;
      break;
    case "Spain,Fall":
      selectSPNCard1 = dict_main.spn_fall;
      break;
    case "Spain,Winter":
      selectSPNCard1 = dict_main.spn_winter;
      break;

    case "France,Spring":
      selectFRNCard1 = dict_main.tsh_spring;
      break;
    case "France,Summer":
      selectFRNCard1 = dict_main.tsh_summer;
      break;
    case "France,Fall":
      selectFRNCard1 = dict_main.tsh_fall;
      break;
    case "France,Winter":
      selectFRNCard1 = dict_main.tsh_winter;
      break;

    default:
      selectGRMCard1 = null;
      selectSPNCard1 = null;
      selectFRNCard1 = null;
  }
  if (selectGRMCard1) {
    return <h1>{selectGRMCard1}</h1>;
  }
  if (selectSPNCard1) {
    return <h1>{selectSPNCard1}</h1>;
  }
  if (selectFRNCard1) {
    return <h1>{selectFRNCard1}</h1>;
  } else {
    return <h1>Please make a selection</h1>;
  }
}
```

The `ReturnComboHeading()` function thus checks which combination is selected and returns the corresponding string from the dictionary.

I have to find a way to loop or map through these combinations and retrieve the correct string from the dictionary, without hard-coding all possible combinations. The reason for this is that sometimes the lists are shorter or longer and I need the code to map/loop through whatever is in the lists.

Thank you for any help and let me know if I should elaborate or explain more.

Here is the SandBox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-tdd-gh5le?file=/src/dict_main.json

Comment: If you're using a dropdown, set `<option value="language_code">`, and not `<option value="Some Pretty Language Descriptor">`, then all you need to do is `dict_main.$code`.

Comment: Thanks @HoldOffHunger for your response. I don't think I completely understand what you mean. As I said, I am fairly new to React and JavaScript. Would you mind elaborating on your solution? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of my colleagues assisted me with this issue, so I would just like to post the answer.

Firstly, I had to change the way my data looks. I changed the names in the data from:

```
{
  "grm_spring": "In Spring time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "grm_summer": "In Summer time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "grm_fall": "In Fall time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "grm_winter": "In Winter time in Germany, words words words ...",

  "spn_spring": "In Spring time in Spain, words words words ...",
  "spn_summer": "In Summer time in Spain, words words words ...",

etc...
}
```

to:

```
{
  "Germany_Spring": "In Spring time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "Germany_Summer": "In Summer time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "Germany_Fall": "In Fall time in Germany, words words words ...",
  "Germany_Winter": "In Winter time in Germany, words words words ...",

  "Spain_Spring": "In Spring time in Spain, words words words ...",
  "Spain_Summer": "In Summer time in Spain, words words words ...",

etc...
}
```

Now, the entire function can be reduced to:

```
export default function ReturnComboHeading(props) {
  const { country, season } = props;
  const dict_main = require("./dict_main.json");

  const heading = dict_main[`${country}_${season}`];

  return <h1>{heading}</h1>;
}
```

Credit to my colleague, thanks!